# kasten k10 installation crypto-svc-.... pod not starting

Tags: kubernetes, backup, rancher

I am trying to install Kasten k10 on rancher Kubernetes. I have a four-node rke cluster on top of which I am trying to install kasten k10. I have used the default installation for kasten k10-5.0.0. While installing, one of the crypto pods is not starting.

- Kubectl get pods -n kasten-io

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
aggregatedapis-svc-88bfc77b9-mrwpq      1/1     Running   0             74m
auth-svc-88977c8f9-67ccn                1/1     Running   2 (73m ago)   74m
catalog-svc-75c69447b8-9qzbv            2/2     Running   0             74m
controllermanager-svc-bf9bfbddc-sz95s   1/1     Running   0             74m
crypto-svc-785dd57f58-lgnwk             2/3     Running   10 (4m ago)   74m
dashboardbff-svc-85fc684477-xg2hc       1/1     Running   0             74m
executor-svc-84b4b99cc7-9xmmq           2/2     Running   0             74m
executor-svc-84b4b99cc7-ghdvl           2/2     Running   0             74m
executor-svc-84b4b99cc7-nt4tw           2/2     Running   0             74m
frontend-svc-ff9f8c85c-qjvc8            1/1     Running   0             74m
gateway-7855695786-452tf                1/1     Running   1 (31m ago)   74m
jobs-svc-57f48dd8c4-xp7ks               1/1     Running   0             74m
k10-grafana-659fdbc659-lrpr7            1/1     Running   0             74m
kanister-svc-85f76b8f7d-9vvlm           1/1     Running   0             74m
logging-svc-86564c7cfc-2d49n            1/1     Running   0             74m
metering-svc-64ddc44bd7-2b7rm           1/1     Running   0             74m
prometheus-server-cf868d45d-qbw7v       2/2     Running   0             74m
state-svc-7bbf8bb589-jx8cm              2/2     Running   0             74m
```

These are the logs for the crypto pod that is not starting.

- kubectl logs pod/crypto-svc-785dd57f58-lgnwk -n kasten-io

````
{"File":"kasten.io/k10/kio/tracing/tracing.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/kio/tracing.StartProfileBuffers","Line":109,"cluster_name":"ffccadbd-b56f-4053-b7e0-d624e0dfc453","hostname":"crypto-svc-785dd57f58-lgnwk","level":"info","msg":"no profile buffers configured","time":"20220827-09:00:18.830Z","version":"5.0.0"}
{"File":"kasten.io/k10/kio/cryptosvc/masterkey.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/kio/cryptosvc.(*CryptoSvc).initializeK10MasterKeyAfterCatalogHealthy","Line":45,"cluster_name":"ffccadbd-b56f-4053-b7e0-d624e0dfc453","error":{"message":"Cluster passkey Secret not found, but Master Key artifacts are in the catalog.\n\t\tPlease recreate Secret \"k10-cluster-passphrase\" with the K10 cluster passkey","function":"kasten.io/k10/kio/cryptosvc.GetPasskeyInfo","linenumber":153,"file":"kasten.io/k10/kio/cryptosvc/masterkey.go:153"},"hostname":"crypto-svc-785dd57f58-lgnwk","level":"error","msg":"Failed to initialize service","time":"20220827-09:00:18.839Z","version":"5.0.0"}
{"File":"kasten.io/k10/kio/utils/swagger_utils.go","Function":"kasten.io/k10/kio/utils.ServerLogger","Line":10,"cluster_name":"ffccadbd-b56f-4053-b7e0-d624e0dfc453","hostname":"crypto-svc-785dd57f58-lgnwk","level":"info","msg":"Serving crypto at http://[::]:8000","time":"20220827-09:00:18.858Z","version":"5.0.0"}```
````

Comment: Error says that some recreating the secret if secret not exist it might stay in pending state.

Comment: Couldn't understand how to create the secret.